# Batch File to copy and rename if

Tags: batch-file, scripting, automation

I am looking to create a batch file that will check the date of a file in the destination directory and if the copy of the file in the source directory is newer rename the existing file in the destination directory and then copy the new file from the source. I know that xcopy /d will handle the copy of the file but I'm not sure on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XCOPY /L option to get a list of files that would be copied, and process the list with FOR /F.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "source=sourcePath"
set "dest=destinationPath"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('xcopy /d /l "%source%\*" "%dest%\"') do (
  if exist "%%F" ( %= This IF weeds out the file count summary at the end =%
    if exist "%dest%\%%~nxF" ren "%dest%\%%~nxF" "someNewName"
    copy "%%F" "%dest%\"
  )
)
```